# How set joomla not to remove "rel" attribute

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5, rel

I want to create an article with a link that has `rel` attribute, but Joomla is removing this attribute. How to make Joomla not to remove my attributes?

I have:

```
<a href = "http://site.com" rel="my_rel">
```

But at page a see:

```
<a href = "http://site.com">
```

I am using Joomla 2.5 and tinyMCE.

Comment: How do you know it's Joomla cropping it?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, in article editor i am incerting my truth html code with rel attribute, but when i saving and toggle tinyMCE - i am not see rel attribute.




May be its tinyMCE cleanup code - i do not know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding in tinymce.init() this:

```
extended_valid_elements: _old_settings_ + ",input[*]"
```

to enable all attributes for tag

Comment: where do I find tinymce.init() ?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to use the [Font Awesome Icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/) which can e.g. be used with the `<i>` tag and a corresponding attribute.

Adding `i[*]` to the *Valid Elements* inside the plugin settings of *TinyMCE* solved the issue for me (*Extensions -> Plugins > Editor - TinyMCE*)

**Note:** It seems like, providing a value for the *Valid Elements* is overriding some default settings. Because I had to add ALL the tags I wanted to allow explicitly. E.g. `i[*],span[*],br,h4,h3`